# C# how to decompile yield-return enumerators

Tags: c#, ienumerable, decompiling, yield-return

I am trying to decompile some C# code that uses IEnumerators with yield-return, but no decompiler bothers to rename the variables to valid C# names. I have tried ILSpy, JustDecompile, dotPeek and Reflector with no success.

Decompiled example so far:

```
private IEnumerator _WaitForSecondsThenStop(float startToFadeTime, float fadeOutLength)
{
    AudioObject.<_WaitForSecondsThenStop>c__Iterator0 <_WaitForSecondsThenStop>c__Iterator = new AudioObject.<_WaitForSecondsThenStop>c__Iterator0();
    <_WaitForSecondsThenStop>c__Iterator.startToFadeTime = startToFadeTime;
    <_WaitForSecondsThenStop>c__Iterator.fadeOutLength = fadeOutLength;
    <_WaitForSecondsThenStop>c__Iterator.<$>startToFadeTime = startToFadeTime;
    <_WaitForSecondsThenStop>c__Iterator.<$>fadeOutLength = fadeOutLength;
    <_WaitForSecondsThenStop>c__Iterator.<>f__this = this;
    return <_WaitForSecondsThenStop>c__Iterator;
}
```

ILSpy is supposedly [able to](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/danielgrunwald/archive/2011/03/06/ilspy-yield-return.aspx) decompile enumerators properly, however it doesn't work for me. Somewhere I've read it might be caused by some optimizations of the code that make it impossible for ILSpy to recognize the patters, so it may be caused by that.

However, what I want to ask is this: Is there a C# decompiler that will rename all the field, variables and classes to valid C# names? I'm fine with the state automaton madness, as long as it compiles as a proper C# code.

Comment: This type of question is specifically off-topic for SO. I'd expect someone with 5k+ site rep to know that.

Comment: Oh yea that's right, I was already thinking of 1 solution that would make it on-topic (at least sort of), and that would be just replace it "manually" with some regexes.

Comment: Which version of ILSpy are you using? The 2.x versions have an option in the View -> Options -> Decompile Enumerators - and if it's checked it should give you the actual yield statement. In 3.x it's done automatically and you can't turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the names with these 4 regexes:

```
Pattern               Replacement       What it fixes
<(\w+)>c__Iterator    Iter_$1           <_WaitForSecondsThenStop>c__Iterator
<(\w+)>_              _L_$1_            <form>__2
<\$?>                 _S_               <$>startToFadeTime
\$(\w+)               _SS_$1            $current
```

EDIT: after some inspection, it still doesn't quite cover everything, I'll update the table once I fix it.